# ¿Cómo puedo comparar horas de un json en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, json, validación

Hola estoy haciendo un app de radio y debo implementar una validación para que se pueda conectar únicamente a ciertas horas (06:00 hasta las 09:05). Estas horas vienen de un Json que es este:

```
["06","00","9","05"]
```

Y entonces lo que necesito es de ese Json armar la hora para poder comparar y poner un mensaje que no puede reproducir si no esta en la hora y si esta en el rango de horas, pues puede reproducir, aquí paso lo que he logrado, ya tengo las horas, pero son simplemente valores del json no está armado como una hora.

```
public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response){
    int hora_desde = response.body().get(0).getAsInt();
    int minuto_desde = response.body().get(1).getAsInt();
    int hora_hasta = response.body().get(2).getAsInt();
    int minuto_hasta = response.body().get(3).getAsInt();

    Log.e(TAG, "La hora desde es: " + hora_desde);
    Log.e(TAG, "Los minutos desde son: " + minuto_desde);
    Log.e(TAG, "La hora hasta es: " + hora_hasta);
    Log.e(TAG, "Los minutos hasta son: " + minuto_hasta);

}
```

Aqui lo que me devuelven los logs:

```
La hora desde es: 6
Los minutos desde son: 0
La hora hasta es: 9
Los minutos hasta son: 5
```

Aprecio si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para poder construir tu hora necesita ser una fecha completa (dia mes año hora minuto segundo), para tu lógica recomiendo tomar la fecha actual y construir la fecha (por ejemplo: 06/01/2020 06:00:00 a 06/01/2020 09:00:00 donde las horas son parametrizadas por tu JSON, entonces para poder lograr esto concatena la fecha sin hora a tus horas así:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String date =sdf.format(new Date());
    String fechacompleta1 = date+ " "+ response.body().get(0)+":"+response.body().get(1);
    String fechacompleta2 = date+ " " +response.body().get(2)+":"+response.body().get(3);

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

    Date fechaHoraActual =  new Date();

    boolean seEncuentraEnRango =fechaHoraActual.after(sdf.parse(fechacompleta1)) && fechaHoraActual.before(sdf.parse(fechacompleta2));
```

Ten en cuenta que el new Date() se instancia con la fecha actual del sistema y de esta depende tu comparación de rangos, lo ideal es que envies fechas con formato desde tu JSON y no solo horas, además que tienes que probar que todo funcione correctamente cuando la hora sea 9 y no 09.

Saludos.

Comment: Disculpa por comentar tarde pero lo intente pero tengo este error, al parecer la fecha no es compatible, podrias ayudarme? Con esto?: W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07/01/2020 "06":"00""
W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:358)
        at com.MainActivity.onResponse(MainActivity.java:148)

Comment: Si, necesitas limpiar tu hora con  fechacompleta1 = fechacompleta1.replaceAll("\"",""); ya que el objeto JSON te trae las comillas tambien.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo arregle de esta manera :) . String fecha1 = date + " " + response.body().get(0).getAsString() + ":" + response.body().get(1).getAsString(); usando el getAsString() resolvio mi problema y ahora compara correctamente :D